# Send array to pbs script

Tags: bash, pbs

I have a bash script that calls `qsub` with several variables:

```
group=group_1
normals=$(IFS=,; echo *.txt)

qsub -v VAR1=$group,VAR2=${normals[@]} [...] run_script.pbs
```

---

**run_script.pbs**

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=16  
#PBS -l walltime=2:00:00  
#PBS -l mem=10GB

group=$VAR1
normals=$VAR2

echo ${normals[@]}
```

In this case, the array `normals` contains multiple file names, but when I try to access these in the .pbs script only the first one is printed.

What is the correct way to pass and access an array in a .pbs script?

Comment: @Inian - exactly

Comment: Was the answer helpful? If it _solved_ your problem, don't forget to mark the answer accepted

Answer (score 3):

You are *not* storing the file list in an array at all. You are just doing command-substitution syntax `$(..)` and storing the output in a variable's context and trying to access it as an array.

The right way to get the list of files (don't need `$(..)`) and store it in an array would be,

```
shopt -s nullglob
fileList=(*.txt)

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=,
printf -v var_list "%s" "${fileList[*]}"
IFS="$oldIFS"
shopt -u nullglob
```

The `nullglob` option is needed to handle the case when the `*.txt` didn't return any files on the current folder. Not including will spit some errors on the console. We unset it with `-u` when we no longer need the option set.

With the `-v` option that `printf` supports, you can store the array output with comma separated format directly into the variable `var_list`

Now you can pass the `$var_list` containing the list of files in comma separated format to the command you want.

```
qsub -v VAR1=$group,VAR2="${var_list}"
```